# Every two people shake hands except for Bob. If the total number of handshakes made were 2014 then what is the number of people Bob shook hands with?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers

In a party, every two people shake hands except for Bob, who only shakes hand with som of the people.No two people shake hands more than once. If the total number of handshakes is $2014$, with how many people does Bob shake hands with?​
Here is an equation i made and tried to find integer solutions to:- $3x^2-7x+4+2y=4028$ where $x$ is the number of people in the party except Bob and $y$ is the number of people Bob shook hands with but after that I am stuck. I used an arithmetic progression to find the number of handshakes by $x$ people but the number of handshakes by Bob adds another unknown quantity. I can try getting to $2014$ as close as possible placing values in $x$. But it doesn't seem to be working.
I used the sum of arithmetic progression formula. Since every person shakes hand with another person only once. We can take an example of let's say $6$ people. The first person will do $5$ handshakes, the second person will do $4$ handshakes and so on, this happens till the second Last person performing only one handshake because there are no more people left for the last person to shake hands with. So $5+4+3+2+1$ we add this up

Comment: You should explain your thoughts and attempts at solving the problem. The site is for getting answers to questions, not for making other people do one's "work". Idea: How many people could there be at this party? Can you bound that number?

Comment: Here is an equation i made and tried to find integer solutions to:- 3x^2-7x+4+y=2014 where x is the number of people in the party except Bob and y is the number of people Bob shook hands with  but after that I am stuck

Comment: I used an arithmetic progression to find the number of handshakes by x people but the number of handshakes by Bob adds another unknown quantity. I can try getting to 2014 as close as possible placing values in x. But it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Good, let $x$ be the number of people _excluding_ Bob. But what is the formula for number of handshakes among $x$ people among whom everybody shakes hands once with everyone else? The $x$ part of your formula I do not understand.

Comment: I used the sum of arithmetic progression formula. Since every person shakes hand with another person only once. We can take an example of let's say 6 people. The first person will do 5 handshakes, the second person will do 4 handshakes and so on, this happens till the second Last person performing only one handshake because there are no more people left for the last person to shake hands with. So 5+4+3+2+1 we add this up.

Comment: What is your sum of arithmetic progression formula that gives $3x^2-7x+4$ or $(3x-4)(x-1)$?

Comment: i can plug in the values to the ap sum formual to find the total number of handshakes by x people ( which is excluding bob). so after plugging in the values it looks like- (x-1)/2*(2(x-1)+(x-2)*1)

Comment: so after finding the number of handshakes done by people excluding bob i can  have y represent the number of people bob shook hands with. then add both up and equate them to 2014... then all i have to do is find integer solution. i am pretty much stuck after that

Comment: Let’s say $x=6$, your $3\cdot6^2-7\cdot6+4 = (3\cdot6-4)(6-1)$ is not equal to $5+4+3+2+1$.

Comment: Sorry i have done a mistake in my previous equation the correct equation shall be :--- (x^2-x)/2

Comment: Since $0< y\le x$, $x^2-x+2y=x(x-1)+2y$ is between $x(x-1)$ and $(x+1)x$. Find out $2\cdot 2014$ is between the product of which two consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: 4028 is not the product of any two consecutive natural numbers closest i can get to it---is the product of 62 and 63 which is 3096.

Comment: Looks good. If pick $x-1=62$ and $x=63$, what is $y$, the number of people Bob shake hands with?

Comment: taking x=63 we have *63^2-63)/2+y=2014.....1953+y=2014....y=61 so the number of people bob shook hands with is 61

Comment: If every step makes sense to you, then now you can summarise the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The number of shakehands between $n$ persons is captured by the equation $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
The sequence starts $\{0,1,3,6,10...\}$, which are the triangular numbers, listed in OEIS under [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217).

The first triangular number $T_n\gt h=2014$ is $T_{64}=2016$, so with $64$ party guests all shaking everyone else's hands, you'd have $2016$ handshakes, which is $2$ too many.

So, Bob doesn't shake hands with $2$ guests, and he doesn't shake his own hand of course, so he shakes hands with $64-3=61$ guests.

This is in line with $T_{63}=1953$, meaning that all other $63$ guests shake hands with each other for $1953$ handshakes, which together with Bob's $61$ handshakes yields the total of $h=1953+61=2014$ handshakes.

A way to  estimate $n=64$ for $T_{64}$ is to take $\sqrt{4028}\approx 63.4$. This is because $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is close to $\frac{n^2}{2}$ for reasonably low $n$. So undo the *division by two* by multiplying your $2014$ by two, then undo the *squaring of n* by taking the square root of $2\times 2014=4028$.